# SelectInput under menuitem is not working

Tags: r, shiny

There is a wrong display in shiny dashboard for the below code. The title "Yet to do" is getting displayed as soon as i run the app. I need that when I click on Bivariate Analysis. What is the issue here. This happened when I introduced selectinput under menu item. Earlier it was working well

```
  library(shinydashboard)
  library(shiny)
  ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Data Analysis"),
  dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("Univariate Analysis", tabName = "Univariate", icon = 
  icon("question"),selectInput("Factors",h5("Factors"),choices = 
  c("","A","B"))),
  menuItem("Bivariate Analysis", tabName = "Bivariate", icon = 
  icon("question")))
  ),
  dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName = "Univariate",fluidRow(box(plotOutput("Plot1"),width = 
  1000,height = 1000),
                                          box(plotOutput("Plot2"),width = 
  1000,height = 1000))),
  tabItem(tabName = "Bivariate",h1("Yet to do")))
  ))
  server <- function(input, output) {

  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Should you be using a `conditionalPanel`: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.11/conditionalPanel.html?

Comment: i tried but you do not nice sliding effect under menuitem right?

Answer (score 0):

It is related having `selectInput()` as `menuItem()`. I tried some options like creating `menuSubItem` etc. but couldn't get it to work. This is probably some bug so you may have to look around for a fix. For now, I'd suggest moving the `selectInput` inside `dashboardBody()` -

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Data Analysis"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Univariate Analysis",
        tabName = "Univariate", icon = icon("question")
        # removing selectInput from here fixes the issue
        # ,selectInput("Factors", h5("Factors"), choices = c("","A","B"))
      ),
      # an option is to have selectInput by itself but probably not the layout you want
      # selectInput("Factors", h5("Factors"), choices = c("","A","B")),
      menuItem("Bivariate Analysis", 
        tabName = "Bivariate", icon = icon("question")
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "Univariate",
        fluidRow(
          # add selectInput somewhere on Univariate page
          selectInput("Factors", h5("Factors"), choices = c("","A","B")),
          box(plotOutput("Plot1"), width = "50%", height = "50%"),
          box(plotOutput("Plot2"), width = "50%", height = "50%")
        )
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "Bivariate",
        h1("Yet to do")
      )
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```